# Selection of the appropriate random structure in a partially non counterbalanced experimental design

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects, experimental-design

We designed a study manipulating two factors: one factor (`FACTOR1`) has 2 levels (A,B), the second factor (`FACTOR2`) has three levels (C,D,E). Because in psychology we often have to carry out unreasonably time-consuming experiments we planned to split the experiment (3by2) in two experiments (2by2) in which participants were exposed to all levels of `FACTOR1` and only two levels of `FACTOR2`. One level (C - the logical reference level) of `FACTOR2` was presented to all participants while the half of participants exposed to D were not exposed to E (and viceversa).

We had 41 participants and 60 different item. I thought we could use mixed models to exploit the better precision in estimating C and by-item-fully crossed design, still keeping decent power to capture differences between D and E, with no need to add a third (by-subjects) factor referring to which Experiment participants were assigned to.

Since the specification of the correct random structure is crucial to gain conservative results I fitted the maximal structure and tested the interaction:

```
y~FACTOR1*FACTOR2+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|sj)+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|it)
```

the model does not converge and possibly because it is trying to
compute the adjustments for those levels of FACTOR2 the participants
were not exposed to (participants that saw only C and E were adjusted
for D as well).

What is our best choice?

use the full specification in the by-item random component only and
"relax" the by-subject component?

```
y~FACTOR1*FACTOR2+(1+FACTOR1|sj)+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|it)
```